# computing daily return/increment on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So ive some timeseries data on which i want to compute daily return/increment, where Daily increment = value_at_time(T)/ value_at_time(T-1)

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,7]) #Sample data frame
df[1:]
out:
 0
 1  2
 2  3
 3  7
df[:-1]
out: 
    0
 0  1
 1  2
 2  3
######### Method 1
df[1:]/df[:-1]
out:
    0
0 NaN
1   1
2   1
3 NaN

######### Method 2
df[1:]/df[:-1].values
out:
          0
1  2.000000
2  1.500000
3  2.333333

######### Method 3
df[1:].values/df[:-1]
out:
   0
0  2
1  1
2  2
```

My questions are that

1. If df[:-1] and df[1:] have only three values (row slices of the
   dataframe) then why doesnt Method_1 work ?
2. Why are method 2 & 3 which are almost similar giving different results?
3. Why using .values in Method_2 makes it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at each

method 1, if you look at what the slices return you can see that the indices don't align:

```
In [87]:
print(df[1:])
print(df[:-1])

   0
1  2
2  3
3  7
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

so then when do the division only 2 columns intersect:

```
In [88]:
df[1:]/df[:-1]

Out[88]:
     0
0  NaN
1  1.0
2  1.0
3  NaN
```

Method 2 produces a np array, this has no index so the division will be performed in order element-wise as expected:

```
In [89]:
df[:-1].values

Out[89]:
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]], dtype=int64)
```

Giving:

```
In [90]:
df[1:]/df[:-1].values

Out[90]:
          0
1  2.000000
2  1.500000
3  2.333333
```

Method 3 is the same reason as method 2

So the question is how to do this in pure pandas? We use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas.DataFrame.shift) to allow you to align the indices as desired:

```
In [92]:
df.shift(-1)/df

Out[92]:
          0
0  2.000000
1  1.500000
2  2.333333
3       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks EdChum but another question was that Method_3 though exactly same as Method_2 doesnt give same output. While Method_2 gives float output, Method_3 rounds them off, why is it so ? Whats happening there with order reversal.

Comment: I get float but my np version is `'1.10.4'` and pandas version is `'0.18.0'` and python 3.4

Comment: pd.__version__ 0.17.1 , numpy.__version__ '1.10.1'. I guess maybe pandas 17.1's bug

Comment: could be, can you upgrade